# Compodoc --includes option example

Tags: angular, compodoc

Can someone please provide me with an example of how to use the --includes option with Compodoc.  I want to include all ts documents within the ClientApp -> app directory with my application files setup in the following structure:

- ClientApp
  -> app (with all ts files under this folder)
  ....
- package.json
- tsconfig.json

My tsconfig.json file has the following:

"compileOnSave": false,
  "include": [
    "./ClientApp",
    "./wwwroot/ts"
  ],

and my package.json has the following:

```
"compodoc": "compodoc -p tsconfig.json -w -s -o"
```

I can't seem to find an '--includes' example to follow.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Could't find any answers too.
Figured out how to implement it:

In your package.json you need to add the `--includes` flag with the path to your markdown folder:

```
"compodoc": "***your options** => add this => --includes ./src/app/markdown/"
```

./src/app.markdown should be pointing to your folder that holds the .md files.
Make sure to include the summary.json as described here => https://compodoc.app/guides/tips-and-tricks.html

Hope that helps.